# How to add specified data to column in datagridview

Tags: datagridview

I want to add my specified data to column but i get error "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index"

```
private void Button1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var result = _transactionService.GetTransactionReport(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2), DateTime.Now);
        foreach (var transaction in result)
        {
            for (int r = 0; r < result.Count; r++)
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows[r].Cells[0].Value = transaction.Number;
                dataGridView1.Rows[r].Cells[1].Value = transaction.DateTime;
                dataGridView1.Rows[r].Cells[1].Value = transaction.Customer.Name;
            }
        }
    }
```

how to add data to row and column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the error being throw on this line:

```
dataGridView1.Rows[r].Cells[0].Value = transaction.Number;
```

I believe you're getting that error because you are referencing a row in your DataGridView that does not exist.  There a number of ways to add a row to a DataGridView.  You can use the [`DataGridViewRowCollection.Add` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fbs04kbx.aspx) to add new row and populate it with values from one of your transaction objects:

```
private void Button1Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    var result = _transactionService.GetTransactionReport(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2), DateTime.Now);
    foreach (var transaction in result) {
        for (int r = 0; r < result.Count; r++) {
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(new object[] { transaction.Number, transaction.DateTime, transaction.Customer.Name });
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this code assumes your DataGridView already has at least three columns.